# Get Address without Internet through Cell Site

Tags: android, geolocation, street-address

I would like to know if it is possible to get the name of an area without internet using the [GsmCellLocation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/gsm/GsmCellLocation.html#getCid()) class; cell ID and Location Area Code?

Yash047